# ASP.NET authentication issue using JWT

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, authorization

I can generate a token using a "very-safe-secret" and I can receive it in my cookies as HttpOnly. Here is my code for that:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace RPG.Utils
{
    public class JWTokenHandler {
        public JWTokenHandler(string payload) {
            _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            _key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("very-safe-secret");
            _tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim("payload", payload)
                }),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(_key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
        }

        public string generateToken() {
            return _tokenHandler.WriteToken(_tokenHandler.CreateToken(_tokenDescriptor));
        }

        private JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler;
        private byte[] _key;
        private SecurityTokenDescriptor _tokenDescriptor;
    }
}
```

My `Program.cs` is the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RPG.Data;
using RPG.Interfaces;
using RPG.Repositories;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("very-safe-secret")),
        AuthenticationType = "Bearer"
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I have a Controller with the tag: `[Authorize]` and it always throws a 401 back no matter in what field I am passing my token.

Here is the endpoint I am calling:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace RPG.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    public class CharacterController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get() {
            return "agyverzes";
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried literally every possible field name I have found on the internet but still noting.
I am using Postman for this as I have no idea how to test it in Swagger.

Comment: Can you please add a full repro including how do you call the endpoint.

Comment: @GuruStron I have edited the post so now it shows the controller. This is literally all the code that has anything to do with JWT in my project.